# Only Add to Array if it doesn't exist

Tags: arrays, powershell, foreach, contains

In PowerShell v2, I'm trying to add only unique values to an array.  I've tried using an if statement that says, roughly, If (-not $Array -contains 'SomeValue'), then add the value, but this only ever works the first time.  I've put a simple code snippet that shows what I'm doing that doesn't work and what I've done as a workaround that does work.  Can someone please let me know where my issue is?

```
Clear-Host
$Words = @('Hello', 'World', 'Hello')

# This will not work
$IncorrectArray = @()
ForEach ($Word in $Words)
{
    If (-not $IncorrectArray -contains $Word)
    {
        $IncorrectArray += $Word
    }
}

Write-Host ('IncorrectArray Count: ' + $IncorrectArray.Length)

# This works as expected
$CorrectArray = @()
ForEach ($Word in $Words)
{
    If ($CorrectArray -contains $Word)
    {
    }
    Else
    {
        $CorrectArray += $Word
    }
}

Write-Host ('CorrectArray Count: ' + $CorrectArray.Length)
```

The Result of the first method is an array containing only one value: "Hello".  The second Method contains two values: "Hello" & "World".  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 17):

To fix your code, try `-notcontains` or at least WRAP your contains-test in parantheses. Atm. your test reads:

> If "NOT array"(if array doens't exist) contains word.

This makes no sense. What you want is:

> If array does not contain word..

That's written like this:

```
If (-not ($IncorrectArray -contains $Word))
```

`-notcontains` is even better, as @dugas suggested.

Answer (score 9):

The first time around, you evaluate -not against an empty array, which returns true, which evaluates to: ($true -contains 'AnyNonEmptyString') which is true, so it adds to the array. The second time around, you evaluate -not against a non-empty array, which returns false, which evaluates to: ($false -contains 'AnyNonEmptyString') which is false, so it doesn't add to the array.

Try breaking your conditions down to see the problem:

```
$IncorrectArray = @()
$x = (-not $IncorrectArray) # Returns true
Write-Host "X is $x"
$x -contains 'hello' # Returns true
```

then add an element to the array:

```
$IncorrectArray += 'hello'
$x = (-not $IncorrectArray) # Returns false
    Write-Host "X is $x"
$x -contains 'hello' # Returns false
```

See the problem? Your current syntax does not express the logic you desire.

You can use the notcontains operator:

```
Clear-Host
$Words = @('Hello', 'World', 'Hello')

# This will work
$IncorrectArray = @()
ForEach ($Word in $Words)
{
  If ($IncorrectArray -notcontains $Word)
  {
    $IncorrectArray += $Word
  }
}
```