# Remove duplicate values from array and convert object into title case

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

I wont to go though a array and remove any object/value which is duplicated in the array.

I try this code the convert the string into array

```
$a = "a,b,a,c,d,a,g,G,h,A,,,,"
$option = [System.StringSplitOptions]::RemoveEmptyEntries
$a= $a.Split(",", $option);
$a= $TextInfo.ToTitleCase($a.Trim())
```

Then I use following to remove any values which is duplicated

```
$a = $a | Select-Object -Unique
```

Which is hit and miss on some list, its working for some list but then for some it doesn't.

Would like to have a array with no duplicate values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could convert your split array to uppercase with `ToUpper()` before getting unique values:

```bsh
❯ $a = "a,b,a,c,d,a,g,G,h,A,,,,"
❯ $option = [System.StringSplitOptions]::RemoveEmptyEntries
❯ $a.Split(",", $option).ToUpper() | Select-Object -Unique
A
B
C
D
G
H
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do this:

```
$a = "a,b,a,c,d,a,g,G,h,A,,,," -split ',' | 
    Where-Object { $_ -match '\S' } |
    ForEach-Object {(Get-Culture).TextInfo.ToTitleCase($_.Trim())} | 
    Select-Object -Unique

$a
```

Output:

```
A
B
C
D
G
H
```

Comment: It looks like if I use this approached it works https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16153609/powershell-only-add-to-array-if-it-doesnt-exist